# Interleave timespan table with new rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL server 2012, 
my data looks like this:

```
**Begin**                    **End**                         **Status**
2018-02-01 00:00:00.000      2018-02-01 02:09:20.180         6
2018-02-01 02:24:50.180      2018-02-01 02:31:50.180         -1
2018-02-01 02:23:50.180      2018-02-01 02:24:20.180         4
2018-02-01 02:42:50.180      2018-02-01 02:47:20.180         4
2018-02-01 02:54:50.180      2018-02-01 02:55:20.180         4
2018-02-01 03:12:20.180      2018-02-01 03:16:50.180         -1
2018-02-01 03:10:50.180      2018-02-01 03:11:20.180         4
2018-02-01 03:27:20.180      2018-02-01 03:30:20.180         4
2018-02-01 03:45:20.180      2018-02-01 03:53:50.180         4
2018-02-01 04:14:50.180      2018-02-01 04:17:50.180         4
2018-02-01 04:32:50.180      2018-02-01 04:33:20.180         3
```

What I want is new insertions between rows, such that the newly inserted row has the **End** of the previous and the **Begin** of the next. This can be achieved with LEAD and LAG. How do I iterate and interleave?

Result:

```
**Begin**                    **End**                         **Status**
2018-02-01 00:00:00.000      2018-02-01 02:09:20.180         6
2018-02-01 02:09:20.180      2018-02-01 02:24:50.180         0
2018-02-01 02:24:50.180      2018-02-01 02:31:50.180         -1
2018-02-01 02:31:50.180      2018-02-01 02:23:50.180         0
2018-02-01 02:23:50.180      2018-02-01 02:24:20.180         4
2018-02-01 02:24:20.180      2018-02-01 02:42:50.180         0
2018-02-01 02:42:50.180      2018-02-01 02:47:20.180         4
2018-02-01 02:47:20.180      2018-02-01 02:54:50.180         0
2018-02-01 02:54:50.180      2018-02-01 02:55:20.180         4
2018-02-01 02:55:20.180      2018-02-01 03:12:20.180         0
2018-02-01 03:12:20.180      2018-02-01 03:16:50.180         -1
2018-02-01 03:16:50.180      2018-02-01 03:10:50.180         0
2018-02-01 03:10:50.180      2018-02-01 03:11:20.180         4
2018-02-01 03:11:20.180      2018-02-01 03:27:20.180         0
2018-02-01 03:27:20.180      2018-02-01 03:30:20.180         4
2018-02-01 03:30:20.180      2018-02-01 03:45:20.180         0
2018-02-01 03:45:20.180      2018-02-01 03:53:50.180         4
2018-02-01 03:53:50.180      2018-02-01 04:14:50.180         0
2018-02-01 04:14:50.180      2018-02-01 04:17:50.180         4
2018-02-01 04:17:50.180      2018-02-01 04:32:50.180         0
2018-02-01 04:32:50.180      2018-02-01 04:33:20.180         3
```

Comment: Your fourth row goes from 02:31 to 02:23, i.e. backwards.  Is this really what you wanted to do?  If so then how are you ordering the initial data set, as it isn't in date order?  To use LEAD/ LAG you will need something to define the order.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    Status = 0,
    [Begin] = LAG(T.[End], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY T.[Begin] ASC),
    [End] = LEAD(T.[Begin], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY T.[Begin] ASC)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

Please validate the `ORDER BY` columns.